# Getting error when trying to construct FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter

Why does this give me an error?  I am stumped.

```
public void filewrite(String filename)
{   
    int lines = 10 + randomnumbers.nextInt(11);
    String randomnumber = Integer.toString(1 + randomnumbers.nextInt(11));

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see the Exception you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) constructor which you are using is declared as throwing an `IOException`. You need to either `catch` it or declare your method as throwing it.

```
public void filewrite(String filename) throws IOException
{   
    int lines = 10 + randomnumbers.nextInt(11);
    String randomnumber = Integer.toString(1 + randomnumbers.nextInt(11));

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
    // use it
}
```

or

```
public void filewrite(String filename)
{   
    int lines = 10 + randomnumbers.nextInt(11);
    String randomnumber = Integer.toString(1 + randomnumbers.nextInt(11));

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've never had to deal with them before, but suffice it to say I bet this will be a extremely helpful in the future.

Comment: @ChristianBaker Take good care to learn about exception types and proper handling strategies.